# Easy .NET XML Library

Tags: .net, xml

Following my question regarding a [.NET YAML Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42071/net-yaml-library)... as there doesn't seem to be great support for YAML in .NET, are there and good open source *really simple* .NET XML libraries.  I just want something where I can pass it a section name and a key and it gives me the value as well as being able to give me a list of all the current sections and keys.

Also, preferably something with a license that allows it to be used commercially.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

isn't the system.xml namespace suficient?

once i had to use it for the simple scenarios that you described and thought that it was a simple and efficient solutions.

take a look at this examples

[Reading Node Trees with XmlNodeReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/443c16cf(VS.71).aspx)
and the [XML Document Object Model (DOM) Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hf9hbf87(VS.80).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Can you use the 3.5 framework? Linq to XML is fantastic, and simple.

Answer (score 1):

Is XSLT / XPath out of the question?  If so, have you considered [JSON.Net](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx)?

Comment: JSON.NET is simply superb, it is far more human readable than .xml, and seems to be better for data transfer.